# A ''strange'' integral from WolframAlpha

Tags: integration, absolute-value, radicals, wolfram-alpha

I want integrate:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \, dx
$$
so I divide for two cases
$$
x>0 \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx= 2\sqrt{x}+c
$$

$$
x<0 \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}} \, dx= -2\sqrt{-x}+c
$$
But [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%201%2F%20sqrt%28%7Cx%7C%29) gives:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \, dx=\left(\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{x} \right)\operatorname{sgn}(x)-\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{x}  +c
$$
How I can interpret this result? Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives $\left(\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{x} \right)\mbox{sgn}(x)-\sqrt{-x}\color{red}{+}\sqrt{x}+c$

Comment: In your results, you wrote $\dfrac{1}{2}$ instead of $2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is just a (half-dirty) trick to put the two cases into one. Put in $-1$ vs. $+1$ for $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and your eyes will be open.

Comment: The trick is to be considered *dirty* because $\sqrt{-1}$ is hybris.

Comment: Thank you. I understand, but I am a bit bewildered by this trick. It seems too wild.

Comment: "hybris", as in offending the gods by thinking one is their equal, or did you maybe mean "hybrid"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think this is a good example (+1) that we have to be cautious what online tools provide us as an answer. Not that it is wrong, but certainly an eye opener and it is justified to be a bit critical.

Comment: In less dirty form, it is used quite often. Splitting a square matrix into a symmetric and an asymmetric part is (not quite the same, but near) that: $2A=A^++A^-= (A+A^t)+(A-A^t)$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't know any offending of the gods but the twisting of math, like that: $-1=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}=\sqrt{+1}=+1$

Comment: It's just a way to write it in one line without having to break it down into two separate cases (this sort of thing is frequently done).

Comment: @GyroGearloose it never gets multiplied with anything. You only need to accept that $\sqrt{-1} - \sqrt{-1} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is not defined for $x=0$, it's not really meaningful to have a single constant of integration for the whole thing. The most general function $F$ (not defined at $0$) for which, at each point $x\ne0$, $F'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$, is
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
-2\sqrt{-x}+c_1 & \text{if $x<0$}\\
2\sqrt{x}+c_2 & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Among these functions there are some that can be extended by continuity at $0$, namely those for which $c_1=c_2$, but they're just a special case. Note that none of these special functions is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that 2 constants are needed for a general solution.